# How does care differ between a Labrador and Cane Corso?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection, compatibility

We have a Labrador of 15 months and we are looking for a Cane Corso puppy. Our Labrador is quite big for a Labrador. Both dogs will be male.

What I do wonder, is if this the best combination, since Labrador's have a complete different character as Cane Corso's.

Anyone that has experience with this 2 dogs combined? I know a Labrador needs a lot of exercise, so we take 3 walks a day, with 2 walks of minimal 1 hour. Can we take the Cane Corso (when full grown) on these long walks too, or would it be bad for their joints?

What should we be aware of when these two type of dogs get together?

Some advice on how to care for these two breeds together would be totally welcome!

Comment: I don't think it's anything to worry about, dogs are pack animals and once the new puppy become part of the pack (you and your family and your dog), things will just be like normal, except you have 2 dogs. Every dog needs exercise, take both on walks, if you think one of them is more tired than the other, then take 1 of them instead of both at different walks.

Comment: If you mean a fully grown Corso then exercise would be necessary.

Comment: Well, the lab is never tired. But he's an idiot :P

Comment: yes but still even though he is an idiot he still needs excersize

Comment: Ofcourse, as you can read, we minimally walk 2 hours a day with him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a lab and a cane corso. They are both 4. We got the lab first when it was 8 weeks old. She is a typical, happy, go-lucky lab - full of energy! We came across a male corso (a few months younger) that needed a home. At this time the lab was about 7 months old and the corso was about 3 months old.

They have been a perfect match! The lab is almost the perfect partner for him as he had trust issues and the Lab helps him put down his guard. The lab is also extremely friendly and would NEVER get over-aggressive with him but is feisty enough to hold her own when they play fight.

The only recommendation I would give is, you may want to consider a female if you have a male already. Not to say that two males won't work but it may be tougher - it's just my opinion. Otherwise, I wouldn't hesitate based on my own personal experience. Good luck to you and your pups!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like from my research is that the Cane Corso needs lots of exercise.

> This working breed needs plenty of physical activity to stay in shape. Plan on taking him for a brisk walk or jog of at least a mile, morning and evening, every day. If you like to bicycle, get an attachment that will allow him to run alongside you.
>
> Go easy on puppies. Their musculoskeletal system isn’t fully developed until they are about 18 months old, so while they need more walks to help burn off their puppy energy, those walks should be shorter and slower.
>
> For mental stimulation, provide this dog with a job. Good employment for a Corso includes herding livestock (your own or a trainer’s), learning tricks, practicing obedience skills, or being involved in a dog sport. Spend at least 20 minutes a day on these types of activities. It’s okay to break it up: for instance, 10 minutes in the morning and 10 minutes in the evening.
>
> Never allow a Corso to run loose. A solid, secure fence is a must. An electronic fence will not prevent him from leaving your property if he chooses to, and it won’t protect your neighbor’s dog or cat if he wanders into your yard.
>
> Finally, be prepared for the amount of care and large bills that can go along with owning a large dog. There’s more poop to scoop, and essentials such as spay/neuter surgery are more expensive for big dogs than for small ones. If your Corso needs surgery for any other reason, the cost of anesthesia will be high because he needs more of it than a small dog, as well as larger amounts of pain medication after surgery. Finally, there are the costs of training class, entry fees for dog sports, and pet-sitting or boarding when you are away from home. Take all of these expenses into consideration before acquiring a Corso because you will be facing them for 10 to 12 years.
> http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/cane-corso#care

Daily walks, romps in a fenced yard, and games of fetch keep his mind and body in shape. Unless these needs are satisfied, the Lab may become a wanderer, a digger, or a chewer.

> The lovable Lab needs to be around his family, and is definitely not a backyard dog. If he's left alone for too long, he'll probably tarnish his saintly reputation: A lonely, bored Lab is apt to dig, chew, or find other destructive outlets for his energy.
> Labs show some variation in their activity levels, but all of them need activity, both physical and mental. Daily 30-minute walks, a romp at the dog park, or a game of fetch, are a few ways to help your Lab burn off energy. However, a puppy should not be taken for too long walks and should play for a few minutes at a time. Labrador Retrievers are considered "workaholics," and will exhaust themselves. It is up to you to end play and training sessions.
> http://dogtime.com/dog-breeds/labrador-retriever#care

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can conclude from it that my lab and a CC will go perfectly together with movement etc. Ofc, not as long as the CC is a puppy, but after that.